# Body.replace no replacing value in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I converted my api to jmeter test. The issue I am facing is that I have in my JSR223 PreProcessor

```
body.replace("${date}", date};
```

But when I run my test the value in the request body remains like this "${date}"

Is there something i am missing on the above statement to replace the value?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax clashes with:

- [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)
- [Groovy String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

So you can just do something like:

```
vars.put('date', date as String)
```

and JMeter will replace `${date}` placeholder in the runtime.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)